# Electrum: display redeem script of a P2SH utxo

Tags: electrum, multi-signature, message-signing

I use Electrum with a multisig wallet. I would like to figure out how to prove ownership of a "coin".

I understand that I need to share the whole redeem script so that it's hash can be verified against the UTXO I want to prove ownership off. And then I need to sign a message using at least N of M (as defined when creating the multisig wallets) private keys corresponding to the public keys in the redeem script.

My question is how can I display the redeem script in Electrum, in a human readable way that allows to clearly identify N, M and all of the public keys?

How can I display the data structure encoding the redeem script on the blockchain, whose hash constitutes the ps2h address (without spending the UTXO)?

Comment: Good question. For the future, i hope wallets will implement lifting Bitcoin Scripts to Miniscript policy: they allow a more natural sight over spending condition (see http://bitcoin.sipa.be/miniscript/) . In the meanwhile i don't have an answer to your question but i think the title should be "how to display the redeemScript on Electrum", feel free to revert the EDIT if i'm wrong!

Comment: I understand. But I'm willing to accept answers that involve using external tools other than Electrum, as long as it is reasonably achievable by a non-programmer. For instance if Electrum can somehow display the redeem script in a binary/hex format, and there is an external tool to decode it, I'm interested.

Answer (score 1):

I did not find a good answer, so I coded a small GUI to perform signatures using private keys, verify a signature using a public key (or an address) and verify a p2sh M-of-N multisig script against a list of N public keys and the parameter M.

This information is easy to find with a simple right click on an address in Electrum (View Details).

https://github.com/PiRK/signverify

I made it primarily for BCHA, but it works for BTC if you paste a legacy p2sh address instead of a CashAddr.